# Jenkins scripted pipeline with sidecar MYSQL container for testing

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I have the below pipeline that would run the actual container along side with MYSQL container to run test.

```
stage('Test - To check MYSQL connect') { 
        def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile.test'
        def mysql = docker.image('mysql:5.6').run('-e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes')
        docker.build("rds-test", "-f ${dockerfile} .")
        def rds_test_image = docker.image('rds-test')
        rds_test_image.inside("--link ${mysql.id}:mysql "){
            sh 'echo "Inside Container"'
        }
    }
```

And i am stuck with the below error

```
Successfully tagged rds-test:latest
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . rds-test
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container d4e0934157d5eb6a9edadef31413d0da44e0e3eaacbb1719fc8d47fbf0a60a2b
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 --link d14340adbef9c95483d0369857dd000edf1b986e9df452b8faaf907fe9e89bf2:mysql -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-jenkinsfile-s3-rds-backup --volumes-from d4e0934157d5eb6a9edadef31413d0da44e0e3eaacbb1719fc8d47fbf0a60a2b -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** rds-test cat
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'rds-test'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /sharp_sanderson AS /fervent_lewin/mysql.
```

Just in case you want to look at the rds-test dockerfile https://github.com/epynic/rds-mysql-s3-backup/tree/feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the running container will not be captured in the return of the `run` method, but rather is stored in the temporary lambda variable of the `withRun` block. To leverage this capability, we would modify your code accordingly:

```
stage('Test - To check MYSQL connect') { 
  def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile.test'
  docker.build("rds-test", "-f ${dockerfile} .")
  def rds_test_image = docker.image('rds-test')

  docker.image('mysql:5.6').withRun('-e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes') { container ->
    rds_test_image.inside("--link ${container.id}:mysql") {
      sh 'echo "Inside Container"'
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see above, running your second container within the code block of the other container's `withRun` makes the container id accessible within the `id` member variable of the temporary lambda variable initialized within the block (named `container` here for convenience).

Note that you can also do a slight code cleanup here by assigning the value of `rds_test_image` to the return of `docker.build("rds-test", "-f ${dockerfile} .")` instead of adding another line of code assigning it to the return of `docker.image('rds-test')`. The new code would also be more stable.

Comment: container-id was not the problem, rather the mysql-container was not ready during the step `rds_test_image.inside("--link ${mysql.id}:mysql "){`, as mentioned `withRun` mas this possible and also destroys the mysql container once the process is done. Thank You. can you link me jenkins-pipeline docs or tutorials with real time docker examples

Comment: one more think `rds_test_image.inside("--link ${container.id}:mysql"){ sh 'ls ' }` why `ls` list the files of the git directory, I was expecting it to list the files in the container, I have a bash script inside the container that needs to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The above case was as the mysql container was not available before `--link` with [Matt Schuchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753133/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-with-sidecar-mysql-container-for-testing/59755312#59755312) suggestion have updated the answer

```
stage('Test - To check MYSQL connect') { 
    def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile.test'
    docker.build("rds-latest", "-f ${dockerfile} .")
    def rds_test_image = docker.image('rds-test:latest')
    docker.image('mysql:5.6').withRun('-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin --name=mysql_server -p 3306:3306') { container ->
        docker.image('mysql:5.6').inside("--link ${container.id}:mysql") {
            /* Wait until mysql service is up */
            sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -hmysql --silent; do sleep 1; done'
        }

        rds_test_image.inside("--link ${container.id}:mysql -e MYSQL_HOST=mysql -e MYSQL_PWD=admin -e USER=root "){
            sh 'bash scripts/test_script.sh'
        }
    }
}
```